# Android Start New View Error: missing instrumentation.class

Tags: android, android-activity

hey, 
i have new activity that extends Activity and when i'm trying to change to her i'm getting the following error:
"the source attachment does not contain the source for the file instrumentation.class"

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this behavior is "normal". I found an answer to this question from a different forum.

> That's normal.  The SDK doesn't include source code for Android
>   classes.  If you step into an Android class while debugging, you'll
>   get the "source not found" message.  Do Run -> Step Return to finish
>   executing the method without source code.

However, when I try to Step Over or Step Return, I still receive this error and the program stops. So, I guess it's an answer, but not a solution. I don't know how to get passed this issue.

Here's a link to the original [forum post](http://markmail.org/message/ssv6fcmi6qqpeqjn)

Update:
Using this link [View Android Source Code in Eclipse](http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html), I found the solution I needed. Find the post by Volure in the comments section. It has a link to a packaged set of Android base code needed to overcome this issue. Put the zip file in the corresponding directory. Then in the Package Explorer, r-click on the jar file, select Properties. In the Java Source Attachment dialog, select External File. Select the zip file. Press OK. Again, r-click the jar file in Package Explorer and select refresh. Test the setup by double-clicking any of the Android classes. You should now see the source.

Hope this saves someone some time. It took me 4 hours of research to discover the solution.